# Trying to update my query to include database size using DBC.DiskSpaceSize, but I'm having issues

Tags: sql, teradata

Trying to update my query to include database size using DBC.DiskSpaceSize, but I'm getting the following error:

`[Teradata Database] [3807] Object 'DBC.DiskSpaceSize' does not exist.`

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  DATABASENAME, TABLENAME, 
  SUM(CURRENTPERM)/ 1024 / 1024 (DECIMAL(10,2)) AS USED_SPACE_MB,
  SUM(MAXPERM)/1024/1024/1024 (DECIMAL(10,2)) AS SPACE_ALLOCATED
FROM
  DBC.DiskSpaceSize
WHERE DATABASENAME = 'My-Database-Name'
AND MAXPERM > 0
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3
```

What is going on?

Comment: Can you check by running like `SELECT *
FROM dbc.TablesV
WHERE TableName = 'DiskSpaceSize' AND TableKind = 'V'`

And confirm table exist

Comment: OR; It may happen so that; you don't have privileges to view it

Comment: @Tushar I tried it and it returned empty columns

Comment: Can you try it as below :

`SELECT 
    DatabaseName,
    SUM(CurrentPerm)/1024/1024 (DECIMAL(10,2)) AS USED_SPACE_MB,
    SUM(MaxPerm)/1024/1024/1024 (DECIMAL(10,2)) AS SPACE_ALLOCATED_GB
FROM 
    DBC.TableSizeV
WHERE 
    DatabaseName = 'My-Database-Name'
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC;`

Comment: In the above query; Replace your database name at `My-Database-Name`;

Comment: Do you get any result ?

Comment: There's `dbc.TableSizeV` and `dbc.DiskSpaceV`